# Is there something like ON INSERT ERROR in SQL using mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine I have a table `Employee` with columns `id, name, company` and a table `EmployeeErrorLog` with the same structure. The column names of the table `Employee` will have a unique constraint on  the column name. I want to run inserts in the table `Employee` using SQL. The question is if there is an error triggered during an insert in table `Employee`, is it possible to make the insert in the table `EmployeeErrorLog`?

Comment: Which SQL tech are you using? Different engines have different capabilities.

Comment: I use mySQL if this is what you mean

Comment: Yes, MySQL is what I was referring to. Not exactly what you're looking for, but MySQL has [`INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax you might be interested in. It lets you silently (without errors, that is) update an existing entry if you try to insert it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into declare handlers for MySql they basically serve the same purpose as try and catch block.

For more information on these you can check them out here.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html

Here is an example of how handlers are used

```
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000' SET @x2 = 1;
->   SET @x = 1;
->   INSERT INTO test.t VALUES (1);
->   SET @x = 2;
->   INSERT INTO test.t VALUES (1);
->   SET @x = 3;
```

Comment: mySql doesn't have try/catch at least not as far as I know but if you check out my edit answer it should get you the same result.

Comment: @ZeRaTuL_jF You should show an appropriated example instead of providing just a link. Links may break here your answer will be saved.